# Simple voting system in Ruby on Rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, voting, vote

I'm doing some simple voting system in my blog.And I have some problems with this.I'm new in Rails.I have this for the moment.

This is my comment.rb

```
  include Mongoid::Document
   field :name, type: String
   field :body, type: String
   field :abusive, type: Boolean, default: false
   validates_presence_of :name, :body
   embedded_in :post, :inverse_of => :comments
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :votes, :as => :votable,:dependent => :destroy

 end
```

And my vote.rb

```
class Vote
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps

field :vote_up 
field :vote_down 
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :comment 
end
```

in my comment controller i have something like this

```
def vote_up
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  if @comment
   comment.votes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id)
   @notice2 = 'You already voted'
  else
    @vote_up = comment.votes.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :votable_id => 1)
    redirect_to @post,  :method => :post
  end
end

def vote_down
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
 comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
 negative_count = comment.votes.find_all { |c| c.vote_down == true} .count
 if negative_count >= 3 
  #here i would like to add,that comment after 3 negative votes is abusive 


end
```

and in my view

```
- if @post.comments.size > 0
 %h2 Comments
 - @post.comments.each do |comment|
  %h3= comment.name
  %p= comment.body  

   %i.icon-black.icon-thumbs-up  
   = link_to "vote_up", vote_up_post_comment_path(@post.id, comment.id), :method => :post


 %i.icon-black.icon-thumbs-down

 = link_to "vote_down", vote_down_post_comment_path(@post.id, comment.id), :method => :post
```

I don't know how to make this work,really.thank you for any tips.

Comment: You have to explain how it is not working with correct error logs and line.

Comment: new or experienced in rails, I would use gem if they exists and fits my needs, like this one https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable. Why would I write a new voting system unless there is a good reason to do so.

Comment: well.i just seams to not work,i don't get any errors,but it just do nothing.

Comment: in addition to the link above here is a tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system.

Comment: Can i use this gem,even if I use Mongoid?

Comment: for mongodb you can use this https://github.com/vinova/voteable_mongo

Comment: thank you.i'm gonna try this one.

Comment: how are your file endings? :) not comment.model should be comment.rb, vote.model should be vote.rb. or is this just a typo thingy? :)

Comment: sorry.yes they are correct comment.rb and vote.rb.Have you got some advise to make my voting work?